# Check for presence of multiple words in list and return list of boolean

Tags: python, list, boolean

I've defined a function that checks if one or more words are in a list, and it works fine, but now I'm trying to figure out how I should change my code so I get a **list** of boolean values depending on whether the word is in the list. These are the two separate functions I've been fiddling with:

**This is the one without booleans, and it works perfectly to print the words and whether or not they appear in the text, but the function doesn't output a boolean value (it just prints, which is a bit messy I know)**

```
def isword(file):
    wordlist=input("Which word(s) would you like to check for in the text? ")
    wordlist=wordlist()
    file=chopup(file) ##This is another function of mine that splits a string(file) into   a list
    for n in range(0,len(wordlist)):
        word=wordlist[n]
        n+=1
        word=word.lower() ##so case doesn't matter when the person enters the word(s)
        if word in file:
            print(word, ":TRUE")
            for i in range(0,len(file)):
                if file[i]==word:
                    print(i)
        else:
            print(word," :FALSE")
```

**This one outputs a boolean but for one word only. I'm wondering how to combine them so that I get a list of booleans as the output, no printing**

```
def isword(file):
    a=True
    wordlist=input("Which word(s) would you like to check for in the text? ")
    wordlist=wordlist()
    file=chopup(file) ##This is another function of mine that splits a string(file) into a list
    for n in range(0,len(wordlist)):
        word=wordlist[n]
        n+=1
        word=word.lower()
        if word in file:
            a=a
        else:
            a=False
    return(a)
```

**I ended up with this, it works pretty well (my variable/function names are actually in French in the project cause this is for homework at a French uni)**

```
def presmot(fichier):
    result=[]
    listemots=input("Entrez le/les mots dont vous voulez vérifier la présence : ")
    listemots=listemots.split()
    fichier=decoupage(fichier)
    for n in range(0,len(listemots)):
        mot=listemots[n]
        mot=mot.lower()
        def testemot(mot):
            a=True
            if mot in fichier:
                a=a
            else:
                a=False
            return(a)
    result=[(mot,testemot(mot)) for mot in listemots] 
    return(result)
```

The only annoying thing is that the Boolean comes up in English, oh well!

Comment: Edited to improve code formatting :)

Comment: Oh, I just did it then! Yea it looked terrible, woops.

Comment: lol no worries just tryin to help out :), you should put the language in there... looks like python

Comment: yep, it is, thanks for tagging it!

Comment: Added the homework tag which you accidentally forgot ;)

Comment: Make a method that gets filename and a list of sought words and `return`s an answer. Ask the user to enter the words outside of this method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in getting input. Use raw_input instead of input.

```
def isword(file):
    wordlist= raw_input("Which word(s) would you like to check for in the text? ").split()
    file=chopup(file)
    return [word.lower() in file for word in wordlist]
```

FYI, you dont need `n+=1`. for loop automatically increments n.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look:

- You're now returning a boolean but that needs to be a list. So you should have `result = []` somewhere in the beginning of your function and `return result` at the end.
- All that's left to do is to append `True` or `False` to that list, for each word that you're considering. This should not be too difficult since you're already computing whether a word is in the file.